# How to hide Typemock Auto-Runner's shields that are all over the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, typemock

Is there a way to hide the huge symbols that Typemock Isolator adds to the Visual Studio editor window once installed - the orange shield at the top and the orange/green shields near each method? I don't need them because I'm using other test runners, but I haven't found a way to hide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Disable the runner, go to tools -> extension manager -> typemock auto-runner -> disable.

**Update (VS 2012):** Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Typemock Smart Runner -> Disable.

Thanks to Alex from Typemock Support for the answer.

Comment: *it is now "TypeMock Smart Runner" as per other answer

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2012:

TOOLS -> Extensions and Updates -> Tools (left had pane under Installed group)

Find Typemock Smart Runner and select and click Disable